# hex number flipped around?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

This is what I call a 'address' in a game I play: 0037F1C8

What I am trying to achieve in vc++ is convert that 'address' into this result: C8 F1 37 00

If you noticed, that result is the 'address', but spit out right to left for the final result of being left to right.

The result is what I then input into a packet I created and then sent to the server of a game.

I need code that will do this in vc++ as I have no clue on how to flip it and space it out like that.

Comment: Maybe you should start accepting a few of the answer people have given you in the past to encourage more help in the future.

Comment: It is automatic when you access the address as (unsigned char*)&address on a little-endian machine.  Like yours.

Comment: Jonathan Wood, I literally have no clue how to use this website still. I recently accepted a answer as I never knew how to accept a answer. Hans Passant, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not explaining what form you want your result in. Are you trying to get an ASCII string with this content?

In any case, the obvious way to put these into a string is by

- Converting the pointer into an integer of appropriate size (apparently 32 bits)
- Extracting each of the bytes of the integer, most reasonably by doing a series of shifts and masks.
- sprintf'ing the four resulting bytes into a string.

The format string you are looking for would be something like: `"%2X %2X %2X %2X"`

An appropriate mask to give you only the lowest byte of an int "i" would be something like `i & 0xff`

Under the circumstances, I'd just declare four ints to put the individual bytes into rather than doing something fancy -- it likely wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: I want this string "0037F1C8" to be this string result "C8 F1 37 00".

Comment: Then just index the appropriate elements of the array and assign them into a fresh character array. A C string is just an array after all.

Comment: As an example, `dest[0] = src[6]` would put the 'C' in the 7th position of the start string into the first position of the target string.

Comment: The first string "0037F1C8" changes on every start up so I cannot always use the string "0037F1C8" to spit out that result. It is always same length of string though. I understand I would have to put into a array, just I still don't understand. Is their anything in the msdn library or something? I will use your information and search further.

Comment: This is a very elementary problem, and would be well below the level of a utility function in the library. Perhaps you haven't learned C++ fully? You might want to read "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup -- after the first couple of chapters, the answer to a problem like this would be very clear. It is only a few lines of code.

Comment: Perry, I code in vc#. I fixed this problem by coding it in vc# and converting to vc++. I am new to vc++.